# Conditional formatting in Google Sheets IF cell contains any spaces

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column set up as below:

**ASIN** **<--(header)**

ASIN1,ASIN2,ASIN3 <--- (first row)

I would like my staff to always enter ASINs separated with commas (as above) and not have spaces anywhere in the cell. I anticipate them to forget this at times so I would like to set up a conditional formatting rule where if the cell contains *any* spaces then it will automatically be flagged.

What formula would work here? The ASIN column range is E2:E so would like the formula to apply to each cell in this range.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this custom formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(E2," ")
```

[image]

Or you can set a Data Validation rule so it flags with red OR directly prohibits the entry when it's not met. You can choose "Show a Warning" or "Reject the input":

```
=NOT(REGEXMATCH(E2," "))
```

[image]

Comment: I like the Data Validation rule - it works! One follow up, how can I tweak it (for a different column of similar structure) so it works for numbers? At the moment, I have a column where its rows are of the form:

Qty1,Qty2,Qty3 

but if I use the data validation rule above, then I can't enter e.g. just "100" (without a comma and additional quantities) as the rule rejects this input.

Comment: Try with: =OR(IFERROR(NOT(REGEXMATCH(E2," "))),ISNUMBER(E2))